# Creating stream based on asynchronously loaded DOM in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I load a set of items through an ajax call - this is my intial DOM:

```
<section class="books">
</section>
```

Through an AJAX call, I load some books from my server, returned as JSON, to create the following DOM structure:

```
<section class="books">
  <section class="book">
    ..
  </section>
  <section class"book">
  ..
  </section>
  # and so on
</section>
```

This is how I perform the AJAX call:

```
buttonClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent queryButton, 'click'

requestStream = buttonClickStream
  .map ->
    bookName = $('#query').val()
    "/books/list?book=#{bookName}"

responseStream = requestStream
  .flatMap (requestUrl) ->
    disableForm()
    Rx.Observable.fromPromise $.getJSON(requestUrl)
```

And by subscribing to the `responseStream` (and transforming the JSON response to HTML), I add it to the DOM like so:

```
booksHTMLStream = responseStream
  .map (json) ->
    _.map(json.books, (book) -> bookTemplate(book))

bookHTMLStream.subscribe(
  (html) ->
    booksContainer.html(html)
)
```

Now, what I want to do is attach a stream for clicks on `<section class="book">` elements, which have been added to the DOM in the first value return from the `booksHTMLStream`. I know I can add this **inside** the `subscribe` block, but this reminds me of callback-soup - and I feel like I'm doing things the wrong way.

I cannot add the steam initially since there are no `<section class="book">` elements at page load, so the stream never fires off any values. So, what I'm wondering is whether it's possible to asynchronously add sources to a stream, or if there's any good way to accomplish what I want without this turning into a messy callback-ish situation?

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bookClickStream = booksHTMLStream
  .take 1
  .flatMap (bookElements) ->
    Rx.Observable.fromArray bookElements
  .flatMap (bookElement) ->
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent bookElement, 'click'
```

Haven't tested this code, but that is roughly the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! :-) Could you explain the thought behind this solution for an uninitiated soul like myself?

Comment: We first apply `.take 1` to only get the first `booksHTML` from `booksHTMLStream`. Then we want to map all book elements to clicks coming from whatever element. First we (flat)map the `bookElements` to a stream of elements. Then the result is a stream of elements. So we just flatMap each element to its click event stream. Just ask if you need more clarifications.

Comment: I have a problem though: `booksHTMLStream` is not defined by the point I need to define the `bookClickStream` (since the HTML is being loaded asynchronously). I need to define the `bookClickStream` before the stream that fetches the HTML used by the `booksClickStream` - is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes. In that code above replace `booksHTMLStream` with `booksHTMLSubject`, then before `bookClickStream` declare `var booksHTMLSubject = new Rx.Subject()`. When `booksHTMLStream` is available, subscribe to it and call `booksHTMLSubject.onNext(x)` inside the subscribe function.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this particular problem by making a click stream for the entire document, and then filtering based on the `event.target`.

```
clickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent document, 'click'

queryStream = clickStream
  .filter (event) ->
    $(event.target).attr('id') == 'query-button'

bookClickStream = clickStream
  .filter (event) ->
    $(event.target).hasClass('book') || $(event.target).parents('.book').length > 0
```

There might be better solutions though, and I'd love to hear them :-)